# Disable blank screen in 12.04

Tags: 12.04, screensaver

After my computer with ubuntu 12.04 has been idle for a short while, the screen will go blank, and even enter standby mode. I have tried this:

1. System Settings -> Brightness and Lock -> Turn off screen... set to "Never"
2. System Settings -> Power -> Suspend when... set to "Don't suspend"

This doesn't change anything.

How can I make sure that the screen will always remain on, forever?

Comment: For me, installing *xscreensaver* did the trick: http://askubuntu.com/a/233055/104264

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try opening a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and then enter the following:

```
gconftool-2 --type bool --set /apps/gnome-screensaver/idle_activation_enabled "false"
```

Comment: Well, this is a completely user-friendly way to manage that setting... and the best is, they have not changed it for three years.

Answer (score 6):

You can install the dconf-tools package and then run dconf-editor.

In dconf-editor, open up the "org" branch, then "gnome" then "desktop" then "screensaver" and you'll see the name-value pairs that set the various screensaver properties.

Change "idle-activation-enabled" to unchecked.

You could also uncheck "lock-enabled" while you're there to prevent it demanding your password when it's been idle too long.

However this might not work! It didn't work for me when I was trying and I can only assume that there is a bug somewhere in xfce4, which is the windows manager I installed on 12.04 instead of Unity. If you also suffer problems, the work-around is to use xset:

```
xset -dpms s off s noblank s 0 0 s noexpose
```

but that only lasts as long as your session.

You can use

```
xset -q
```

to see what the current settings are. It basically overrides the settings in /etc/X11/xorg.conf

You would have to put it into your .profile to re-apply it every session.

Answer (score 1):

managed to fix it by putting: "@xset s off"    in my autostart file (after all other programs) and setting session idle timeout to its max value in dconf-editor

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer the question. Would mind adding how to find the file and how to change the settings in the dconf-editor?

Answer (score 0):

the only way I could stop the blank screen was to install `xscreensaver`
which will then let you disable the `gnomescreensaver daemon`
you can also remove the `gnome-screensaver`

then set `xscreensaver` to *'no screen saver'*

to have xscreensaver start at log on
open startup applications then add

```
name = xscreensaver

command = xscreensaver -nosplash
```

then save the settings  ...

Answer (score 0):

I tried the selected answer as well as:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver idle-activation-enabled false
```

Both did not solve the issue with me. I found [this](http://blog.projectz.me/2012/06/25/disable-the-lock-screen-and-screen-blank-on-ubuntu-12-04/) that ended up working. I'm sure there is some configuration option that would have solved the issue without me having to remove the package entirely, but I didn't feel like spending too much time on it.

```
sudo apt-get remove acpi-support acpid
```