# Unable to disable screen saver

Tags: screensaver

I have set 'Turn screen off' to Never in Brightness and Lock, but my screen still goes dark after some time being idle, unless I'm watching a movie in VLC or some other media player.

What can I do to make it so my screen never goes dark regardless of whether the computer is idle or not?

Comment: System Settings -> Brightness and Lock.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable blank screen in 12.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/184111/disable-blank-screen-in-12-04)

Answer (score 0):

There's a setting called "Disable Screensaver". Do you ave this option checked?
You can find it in Tools>Preferences>Video (Select "All" under Show Settings instead of "Simple") and click on "Video" in the left column. About the middle of the box you should see "Disable Screensaver".