# Screen goes black every Tuesday?

Tags: 10.04, touchscreen, offline, idle

I'm managing 100+ (mostly offline) [KDS 66T](http://www.surpass.com.au/pos/pos-teminals/7-senor-15-all-in-one-kds-66-terminal.html) touchscreens running Ubuntu 10.04.1 LTS (lucid).

I recently noticed that the two (offline) test machines in our office have black screens every Wednesday morning. A touch removes the black and the displays seem to display their offline browser movies just fine for a week again, so it does seem to be related to idleness - i've set the date back and it turns out that it occurs while idle before 11:48 PM on Tuesdays. There are no crontabs for the active user or root.

I've already tried the screensaver and power management GUIs, a [modified xorg.conf](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2062608) and [gconftool-2](https://askubuntu.com/a/186475/42522), to no avail. All those settings seem to be for daily idle behavior.

What could cause these offline distros to blank the screen every week? And could i prevent that using an automated script ran from a USB stick? These machines lack keyboards and savvy users, so getting them to alter BIOS settings to perform a full system upgrade is out of the question.

Comment: Ubuntu 10.04 is only supported for servers and unfortunately, we don't support end-of-life releases of Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks. Perhaps XP was the cheaper option. Anyway, maybe someone else can help me.

Comment: So should he just update the version of Ubuntu to one which is supported? In any case, this question deserves a bounty which sadly I cannot provide due to having very low reputation.

Comment: @luchonacho The KDS 66T has only one easily accessible USB port, and sending out hubs and keyboards as well as training people to perform an upgrade would likely not fly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sleep 10; killall gnome-screensaver
```

In `~/.config/autostart/myscript.desktop` might work.

`sleep 5` didn't.

```
gnome-screensaver-command --inhibit
```

did, but the machine spontaneously rebooted at Tuesday 11:30 PM.

I might have to resort to [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/343175/42522) or [this](https://superuser.com/a/67766/103551).

Weekly reboots at night could be a feature, so i'll call it that.
This is my final script, if anyone else is stuck maintaining legacy machines:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# sleep 5; killall gnome-screensaver  # too soon
gnome-screensaver-command inhibit
```

I checked `last -x` and according to `cat /var/log/messages |grep 23:30:0`, rsyslogd 4.2.0 exited on signal 15 ([SIGTERM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16723690/819417)) from itself at 23:30:01. I found the reboot cause via [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/114551/16521): `cron`. But even as root, `crontab -l` says there are no crontabs!

Sure enough, `cat /etc/crontab` shows `30 23 * * 2 root reboot`. [Root has its own crontab.](https://superuser.com/a/290114/103551)